# В старой версии PHP не работает код - unexpected [, expecting )

Tags: php, json

В версии php-5.3.21 скрипт не работает - `syntax error unexpected [, expecting )`, в более поздних - работает. Как исправить?

```
<?php
$key = 'key';
$url = 'url';
echo json_encode([ //ошибка тут
'initialPreview' => ["<img style='height:160px' src='http://path.to.uploaded.file/{$key}.jpg' class='file-preview-image'>",],
'initialPreviewConfig' => [['caption' => "Architecture-{$key}.jpg", 'width' => '120px', 'url' => $url, 'key' => $key],],
'append' => true]);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Массив (тип array) может быть создан языковой конструкцией array(). language construct. В качестве параметров она принимает любое количество разделенных запятыми пар key => value (ключ => значение).
>
> **Начиная с PHP 5.4** возможно использовать короткий синтаксис определения массивов, который заменяет языковую конструкцию **array() на []**.

http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php